# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" Error During ChangeListener Execution

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, listener, changelistener

i am getting **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException** at  **this.commaPos = Name.indexOf("   ");** line of my project. The concept is that i have 5 JButtons of ships, and when you click, you place the ship on a Board for a battleship game. Lot of time now i am stuck at this. Any ideas ? Thank you. !

**EDIT:
I changed the name of String name to String nname. Now i get the same error at the next line.
this.commaPos = nname.indexOf(",");**

```
 public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event)
  {

    JButton currentButton = (JButton)event.getSource();
      System.out.println("STATE CHANGED");
    String nname = currentButton.getName();
    this.commaPos = nname.indexOf(",");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(nname.substring(0, commaPos));
    int y = Integer.parseInt(nname.substring(commaPos + 1));

    checkDeletable(x, y);

    if (currentButton.getName().equals(""))
      return;
    if (this.shipSelected == null) {
      return;
    }
    this.shipSelected.setPos(x, y);

    clearOldCoords();
    boolean valid = getShipCoords();
    paintShip(valid);

    if ((currentButton.isFocusOwner()) && (valid))
      placeShip();
  }
```

Here i use the change listener:

```
{
 for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x ++) {
            this.myBoard[x][y] = new JButton();
            this.myBoard[x][y].setMargin(margins); 
            this.myBoard[x][y].setToolTipText(x + "," + y);
            this.myBoard[x][y].setName(null);
            this.myBoard[x][y].setIcon(this.sea);
            this.myBoard[x][y].addChangeListener(this);
            this.myBoard[x][y].addMouseListener(this);

            myBoard.add(this.myBoard[x][y]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Found it guys, i forgot to put the correct name at the for loop here:
this.myBoard[x][y].setName(null);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name (bad name for a variable since all variable names should begin with a lower case letter) is null and likely it's because you've never set it. Why worry about a JButton's name anyway? Why not check the actionCommand instead?

It seems a bit unusual that you're JButton is triggering a ChangeListener and not an ActionListener. Can you give us more information about what this bit of code is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Maybe the OP meant `getText` instead of `getName`?

Comment: Tried both and none works....

Comment: Any other ideas ?

@hovercraft... This code drags a ship from a JButton, and places it to a Board for a BATTLESHIP game project

Comment: @mkontakis: it's hard to guess what else is wrong without more context. I agree that an [sscce](http:sscce.org) would help greatly, a small program that tries to do nothing but the bare minimum of your current problem to illustrate the problem for us.